# Python: Can the pydoc module output HTML docs with relative paths?

Tags: python, html, pydoc

I am using the pydoc module to output documentation for some types which I have defined with the C API. The types I want to document don't exist until the interpreter has been embedded inside my C program, so I can not use the pydoc command.

I get my C code to call a function which does something like this:

```
d = pydoc.HTMLDoc()
content = d.docmodule(sys.modules["mymodule"])
```

This works, but generates HTML pages with hard coded 'file:/' link targets. Is there a way to use relative paths for links?

(Extra points for a better way to document types defined in the C API)

Comment: This question has two questions- how to document C-API code and how to fix the hard coded paths. It should be split up.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org) does a better job at this. Here is how you document a C domain:

http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#the-c-domain

Answer (score 0):

No, per the source code, the link comes from a file path and can't be overridden.

```
try:
   path = inspect.getabsfile(object)
   url = urllib.parse.quote(path)
   filelink = self.filelink(url, path)
except TypeError:
   filelink = '(built-in)'
```

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/55d24edaadba4ee90f464d88b44075649788f128/Lib/pydoc.py#L751