# Is there a way to get pydoc to generate docs for just a module and its submodules?

Tags: python, pydoc

I know sphinx and pdoc3 exist, but I'm trying to use pydocs despite my better judgment.

This invocation

```
python -m pydoc -w .\\
```

will

- generate docs for all modules including things I don't want such as doc for /tests/
- put all documents in root of source folder
- create absolute path links instead relative path links

Here [is a test repo on Github](https://github.com/matthewdeanmartin/pydoc_experiments/blob/main/generate_docs.sh).

I'd like to not generate the docs for /tests/. I'd like the output to go into the /docs/ and not junk up the root. I've already determined that [we can't get relative links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389280/python-can-the-pydoc-module-output-html-docs-with-relative-paths/69965537).

I've seen recommendations for invoking pydoc once per source file, but I don't want to change the doc generating script each time I add a new file.